# Failed to generate a Let's Encrypt certificate on Asustor NAS with error Ref. 5402

Tags: ssl, nas, certificate, asustor

While trying to generate a Let's Encrypt certificate for my Asustor NAS through Settings -> Certificate Manager (following the [instructions](https://www.asustor.com/en/online/College_topic?topic=324#hs32)), the process repeatedly failed with error `Ref. 5402`. Uninstalling/Reinstalling `Let's Encrypt ACME Client` from the Asustor `App Central` didn't help. What else can I try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Tl;DR

ssh into the NAS using a terminal and run the following commands

```sh
rm -rf /volume1/.@plugins/AppCentral/python3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/~ertbot
rm -rf /volume1/.@plugins/AppCentral/python3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/~ertbot-2.6.0.dist-info
```

Then proceed back to the certificate manager GUI, follow the instructions, and the process should work.

### More info:

After failing the UI, I ssh'd into the NAS and attempted to run `certbot` (the tool used by Let's Encrypt under the hood) manually, and install the generated certficate manually. However, that failed with the following error:

```sh
An unexpected error occurred:
Exception: Duplicate plugin name manual from certbot and -ertbot.
Ask for help or search for solutions at https://community.letsencrypt.org. See the logfile /tmp/certbot-log-bufbgpei/log or re-run Certbot with -v for more details.
nic@LaNube:/volume1 $ cat  /tmp/certbot-log-bufbgpei/log
2024-03-02 15:03:00,062:DEBUG:certbot._internal.log:Exiting abnormally:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/certbot", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/local/AppCentral/letsencrypt/data/module/lib/python3.10/site-packages/certbot/main.py", line 19, in main
    return internal_main.main(cli_args)
  File "/usr/local/AppCentral/letsencrypt/data/module/lib/python3.10/site-packages/certbot/_internal/main.py", line 1835, in main
    plugins = plugins_disco.PluginsRegistry.find_all()
  File "/usr/local/AppCentral/letsencrypt/data/module/lib/python3.10/site-packages/certbot/_internal/plugins/disco.py", line 192, in find_all
    cls._load_entry_point(entry_point, plugins)
  File "/usr/local/AppCentral/letsencrypt/data/module/lib/python3.10/site-packages/certbot/_internal/plugins/disco.py", line 204, in _load_entry_point
    raise Exception("Duplicate plugin name {0} from {1} and {2}.".format(
Exception: Duplicate plugin name manual from certbot and -ertbot.
2024-03-02 15:03:00,063:ERROR:certbot._internal.log:An unexpected error occurred:
2024-03-02 15:03:00,063:ERROR:certbot._internal.log:Exception: Duplicate plugin name manual from certbot and -ertbot.
```

`cerbot` fails because it finds two sets of plugins, one in the `cerbot` install, and one from `~ertbot`. Deleting the `~ertbot` install resolves the duplicate plugin issue, and doesn't seem to have an adverse effect on the actual Let's Encypt instance. This extra package seems to be installed by default by the App Central installer.